# Start animation when element is visible

Tags: jquery

Is there anyway I can make the progress bars start when they are visible on screen? Because now they start as soon as the page is loaded even though they are further down the page. Can you make them start when you reach them?

jsfiddle.net/33ne8j1d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a scroll event as follows:

```
$(document).bind('scroll', function(ev) {
    var scrollOffset = $(document).scrollTop();
    var containerOffset = $('#pbar').offset().top - window.innerHeight;
    if (scrollOffset > containerOffset) {
      var animate = setInterval(function() {
        loading();
      }, time);
       // unbind event
        $(document).unbind('scroll');
    }
});
```

});

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33ne8j1d/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind an event listener to the scroll, where you then check if the scrollTop of the page is bigger than the offsetTop of the loader, in case it is then you can start the animation. I'll post an example shortly